# SQL BETWEEN with STR_TO_DATE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all the values in between some dates but for some reason its only returning the name of the columns.

For example if i give the following attributes GEO = Ontario and REF_DATE between jan-98 and mar-98 then this would be the expected output.

[image: Expected output]

But I'm only getting this.

[image: Actual output]

```sql
SELECT * FROM eecs3311.`18100205`   
WHERE REF_DATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('jan-98', '%b-%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('feb-99', '%b-%y')  
AND GEO = 'Ontario';
```

after a lot of tries I know that the issue is somewhere in the between statement but I don't know what it is

Comment: What is the data type of `REF_DATE` column?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some sample data with realistic values.

Comment: @PM77-1 it is TEXT

Comment: Try wrapping `REF_DATE` with the `STR_TO_DATE(, '%b-%y')` function call

Comment: @JettoMartínez I did try that it still doesn’t work

Comment: Doing a simple `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('jan-98', '%b-%y')` returns `NULL`. That could be the root of the problem since `REF_DATA` has that pattern. Actually, trying to use the `%b` flag alone returns `NULL`. I think it's not a valid `DATE` value to begin with because it doesn't have a day.

Comment: Try with the following in your `WHERE` clause: `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('02-',REF_DATE), '%d-%b-%y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-jan-98', '%d-%b-%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('28-feb-99', '%d-%b-%y')`

Comment: Great to hear! I'll add it as an answer, so please consider marking it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `REF_DATE` lacks a day, which is necessary for the `DATE` data type. This applies to the dates in the `BETWEEN` part of your `WHERE` as well.

A fix/hack for this, since you are looking for a range, is to set the day for `REF_DATE` as the second of the month, and filter looking between the first day of January and the last day of February.

```
SELECT * FROM eecs3311.`18100205`   
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('02-', REF_DATE), '%d-%b-%y') 
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-jan-98', '%d-%b-%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('28-feb-99', '%d-%b-%y')
AND GEO = 'Ontario';
```

Using STR_TO_DATE in the comparison isn't even necessary. You could even rewrite it as

```
SELECT * FROM eecs3311.`18100205`   
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('02-', REF_DATE), '%d-%b-%y') 
    BETWEEN DATE('1998-01-01') AND DATE('1999-02-28')
AND GEO = 'Ontario';
```

and get the same result.

I'm guessing it is out of your control, but this is one of the reasons why storing dates as text in a database is a bad idea.

Comment: I cant upvote apparently i need a better reputation

Comment: There should be a checkmark. That marks your question as resolved, meaning that this answer fixed your problem.